# Junit - assert the list contains

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

I'm creating a List (ArrayList) that contains few elements. 
I want to make sure it contains the elements I added.
now, this works only some of the times, since the order changes:

```
@Test
public void testThreeReporters(){
    ClientConfig myConfig = new ClientConfigFactory().getConfig().withMetricsReporters(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.LOG, ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.GRAPHITE, ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.CLOUD_WATCH)));
    List<ScheduledReporter> reporters = MetricsFactory.configureMetricsReporters(MetricsFactory.createMetricsClient(),myConfig);
    assertEquals(3, reporters.size());

    assertTrue(reporters.get(2) instanceof Slf4jReporter);
    assertTrue(reporters.get(1) instanceof GraphiteReporter);
    assertTrue(reporters.get(0) instanceof CloudWatchReporter);
}
```

I want to use 'contains' in order to not be depend on the order.
I tried something like:

```
 assertTrue(Arrays.asList(reporters).contains((Arrays.asList(ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.LOG, ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.GRAPHITE, ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.CLOUD_WATCH))));
```

and some other combinations, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - Surely you've been here long enough to know that this isn't good enough...

Comment: It really depends on the implementation of "MetricsFactory.configureMetricsReporters". If it add elements to the list in order it visits it in myConfig, then your problem is simple and you just need to add/enforce ordering in your myConfig. You can use TreeSet for that https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really an easy way to do this with plain JUnit out of the box.
You could develop a helper method to make this easy using the technique demonstrated by [@JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) in his answer.

Or you could use an additional testing library that can help with this.
For example using [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) you could do this:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

// ...

assertThat(reporters).extracting("class").contains(
    Slf4jReporter.class,
    GraphiteReporter.class,
    CloudWatchReporter.class
);
```

If you use Maven, you can add assertj dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Getting 'Cannot resolve method 'assertThat(java.util.List<...>)' on the 'reporters'.

Comment: Just like for assertTrue(), you need to statically import the method. As explained in the documentation: http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html.

Comment: @user2880391 make you have imported `assertThat` from assertj, not from junit: `import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;`

Comment: great. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 18):

```
assertEquals(3, reporters.size());
assertTrue(reporters.stream().anyMatch(e -> e instanceof Slf4jReporter));
assertTrue(reporters.stream().anyMatch(e -> e instanceof GraphiteReporter));
assertTrue(reporters.stream().anyMatch(e -> e instanceof CloudWatchReporter));
```

Comment: looks good, but if I'm not mistaken - I can't use lambda expression in Java 7.

Comment: Then use Java 8, or write yourself a method that returns true if an element of a list is an instance of a given class, and call that method instead of using the built-in stream methods. Or use Guava, that has such built-in utility mehods. Or use AssertJ like janos suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to check if the `reporters` list contains a list, which it doesn't since you've specified it contains instances of `ScheduledReporter`. I've not used any of those classes, so I can't provide a more elegant solution, but the following should work:

```
@Test
public void testThreeReporters() {
    ClientConfig myConfig = new ClientConfigFactory().getConfig().withMetricsReporters(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.LOG, ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.GRAPHITE, ClientConfig.MetricsReporterType.CLOUD_WATCH)));
    List<ScheduledReporter> reporters = MetricsFactory.configureMetricsReporters(MetricsFactory.createMetricsClient(),myConfig);
    assertEquals(3, reporters.size());

    assertTrue("No Slf4jReporter was found", containsReporter(reporters, Slf4jReporter.class));
    assertTrue("No GraphiteReporter was found", containsReporter(reportera, GraphiteReporter.class));
    assertTrue("No CloudWatchReporter was found", containsReporter(reporters, CloudWatchReporter.class));
}

/**
 * @return {@code true} if {@code reporters} contains an object of type
 *         {@code expectedClass}, otherwise {@code false}.
 */
private boolean containsReporter(List<ScheduledReporter> reporters, Class expectedClass) {
    for (ScheduledReporter reporter : reporters) {
        if (expectedClass.isInstance(reporter)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use boolean variables and interate through the Array. If you have found the element that you want, set the bool variable on true. After the iteration, Assert that the variables are true.